# Does sqoop spill temporary data to disk

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

As I understand sqoop, it launches few mappers on different data nodes making jdbc connection with RDBMS. Once connection is formed data is transferred to HDFS.

Just trying to understand, does sqoop mapper spill data temporary on disk (data node)? I know spilling happens in MapReduce but not sure about sqoop job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems **sqoop-import runs on mapper and doesn't spill**. And **sqoop-merge runs on map-reduce and does spill**. You can check it on Job tracker during sqoop import run.

Have a look at this part of sqoop import log, it does not spill, fetches and writes to hdfs:

```
INFO [main] ... mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBRecordReader: Using query:  SELECT...
[main] mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader: Executing query:  SELECT...
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.snappy]
INFO [Thread-16] ...mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper: Auto-progress thread is finished. keepGoing=false
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task:attempt_1489705733959_2462784_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_1489705733959_2462784_m_000000_0' to hdfs://
```

Have a look at this sqoop-merge log(skipped some rows), it spills on disk (note **Spilling map output** in the log):

```
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://bla-bla/part-m-00000:0+48322717
    ...
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
    ...
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 1024
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 751619264
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 1073741824
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 268435452; length = 67108864
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$**MapOutputBuffer**
    INFO [main] com.pepperdata.supervisor.agent.resource.r: Datanode bla-bla is LOCAL.
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.snappy]
    ...
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: **Starting flush of map output**
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: **Spilling map output**
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: **bufstart** = 0; **bufend** = 184775274; bufvoid = 1073741824
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 268435452(1073741808); kvend = 267347800(1069391200); length = 1087653/67108864
    INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.snappy]
[main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
    ...Task:attempt_1489705733959_2479291_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
```